# InterviewBit - Find path to given node

Tags: javascript, tree, tree-traversal

I am practicing InterviewBit challenge [Path to Given Node](https://www.interviewbit.com/problems/path-to-given-node/), but I keep having problems:

First if I keep my helper function (traverse) in the structure like this, when I run the code it says traverse is not defined.

I tried moving the function inside `solve(A, B)` but then it says I don't get the correct result. My code is at the bottom.

The question is simple: find the path to the node B in binary tree A.

**Problem Description:**

> Given a Binary Tree A containing N nodes.
>
> You need to find the path from Root to a given node B.
>
> NOTE:
>
> No two nodes in the tree have same data values.
> You can assume that B is present in the tree A and a path always exists.
>
> #### Example Input
>
> Input 1:
>
> A =
>
> ```
>        1
>      /   \
>     2     3
>    / \   / \
>   4   5 6   7
> ```
>
> B = 5
>
> **Input 2:**
>
> A =
>
> ```
>        1
>      /   \
>     2     3
>    / \     \
>   4   5     6
> ```
>
> B = 1
>
> #### Example Output
>
> **Output 1:**
>
> [1, 2, 5]
>
> **Output 2:**
>
> [1]
>
> ```
> // Definition for a  binary tree node
> //    function TreeNode(data){
> //      this.data = data
> //      this.left = null
> //      this.right = null
> //    }
> ```

### My code

```
module.exports = { 
 //param A : root node of tree
 //param B : integer
 //return a array of integers
    solve : function(A, B){
        // traverse tree
        // each traversal append a new node 
        // if the leaf is not the node, return earlier traversal
        // like if from left to right we find nothing at all, we return earlier traversal
        path = traverse(A, B, []);
        return path;
    },
    traverse: function(node, target, traversal) {
        if (node) {
            traversal.push(node.data);
            if (node.data === target) return traversal;
            traversal = traverse(node.left, target, traversal);
            traversal = traverse(node.right, target, traversal);
            traversal.pop();
        }
        return traversal;
    },
};
```

Comment: Do you have a link to the code challenge?

Comment: https://www.interviewbit.com/problems/path-to-given-node/ 
Sure! It is this one! I thought of posting the link but was not sure about the forum's policy on external links! I'm preparing this for a JS interview so I'm really trying to solve it in JS!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

When you define `traverse` as a property of the exported object, you need to call it as `this.traverse()`. But it seems better to do the alternative and define it as a local function in the scope of `solve`.

The problem that you then bump into is that even when you find a path, you still `.pop()` elements from it, so that will not work.

When coming back from a recursive call that found the path, you should not search any further and immediately return that *same* path to the caller, who will do the same, ... until the original caller gets that path.

Another thing you should avoid: don't define `path` as a global variable. Declare it explicitly with `const`, `let` or `var`.

So change as follows:

```
    solve : function(A, B){
        function traverse(node, target, traversal) {
            if (node) {
                traversal.push(node.data);
                if (node.data === target) return traversal;
                let success = traverse(node.left, target, traversal);
                if (success) return success;
                success = traverse(node.right, target, traversal);
                if (success) return success;
                traversal.pop();
            }
        }

        // Declare!
        let path = traverse(A, B, []);
        return path;
```

This will fix it.

Now think how you can do better, and avoid passing along a third argument. You can use the `solve` function recursively and build the correct path when *backtracking* out of recursion.

Comment: Thank you so much! I probably should draw out the call stack more as I get confused easily hahaha. I'll try to think about only using solve.